# how to copy a curve in geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have a beziercurve and i want to copy that curve with geometry nodes.

Unfortunately my knowledge of geometry nodes is limited so i don't know why this doesn't work.

Can anybody show me how this works? And/or why mine doesn't?

Node tree:

[image]

result:

[image]

blend file:

sorry, had to use dropbox, blend-exchange doesn't work for me right now:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/1wphst0tkj1rvbh/copy%20curve%20probl.blend?dl=0

Of course Robin is right, instancing would solve the described problem.

But...

the "end goal" is to concatenate two curves....so that the position and handle positions of the end of one curve is the same as the other curve start position. So i thought this "easy" case would help solving that ;)

Comment: I'm being dim. I'm not getting why instancing the curve on a point, and realizing the instance, won't do.

Comment: the "end goal" is to concatenate two curves....so that the position and handle positions of the end of one curve is the same as the other curve start position ;) and that's why instancing won't help.

Comment: Not working, I think, because _Capture Attribute_ passes attributes down the green geometry branch it is on, between different states of _that_ Geometry. You need to _Transfer Attribute_ s between independent geometry branches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is what you're after.. it takes a single-Bezier-spline curve as input on an (arbitrary) modified object, and 'manually' generates a copy of the input curve:

[image]

It generates an 'any-old' curve with the same number of points, and then transfers all the necessary attributes by index.

Blend-File [Here](https://pasteall.org/blend/3419d45c557b4afeb18b61273bb0480a), Blender 3.2a

Comment: Blend-Exchange  must be playing up at the moment? 3.2a, because I don't want to hack earlier versions of Blender to do what later versions will do anyway,, I lose track of where ele it might work :)

Comment: thank you! didn't know that difference of capture and transfer ;)

Comment: @Chris np! I can't remember where I first heard the difference phrased that way, but it sure helped understand what's going on. :)